# Remove Splash screen from cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I am trying to remove the apache cordova is loading screen before the app opens up. The following are the things I tried

1.In config.xml I added

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

This did not work

2.In index.js, I added

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

The app did not open up once I added the line

3. I tried

   cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen

It says Plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" is not present in the project. See `cordova plugin list`.

Can someone help me with this ??

Answer (score 0):

when I've had similar things happen I usually just...

```
cordova platforms rm android
cordova platforms rm ios
cordova platforms add android
cordova platforms add ios
```

can you try?